# Programmatically Change System Network (Proxy) settings

Tags: cocoa, macos, networking, settings

Is there a way, from within a Cocoa application to change the system network settings (specifically, the proxy settings).  I've found that there is a file called *preferences.plist* in */Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration* that has the settings I want, but I can't figure out how to get the system to process changes to this file without rebooting.

Can this be done programmatically, or at least by launching some command? (This solution would probably be 10.5.x only, I'm assuming)

Since I can change these settings in System Preferences immediately, there must be some way, it just eludes me ....

Thanks!

Comment: Don't go editing a plist like that directly, especially one in the /Library/ directory. Your application's user may not even have write permissions for it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the [SystemConfiguration](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_Intro/SC_Intro.html) framework, specifically the Proxies Dictionary (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_UnderstandSchema/SC_UnderstandSchema.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001065-CH203-CHDIHDCG) for more details).

Comment: Would this be accessibl  from the iOS sdk too? I'm looking for at way to do this on iOS...

Comment: No, the SystemConfiguration.framework's Reachability capabilities are the only ones available on iOS.