# porting tsocks to OS X cocoa

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, sockets, proxy

I have encountered a small problem: `tsocks` only works on programs that use the POSIX api for connecting on OS X. I have successfully written a small library that replaces the POSIX `connect` call with a socks5 wrapper in the style that `tsocks` does.

Now I have a program (specifically Spotify Installer) that uses the OS X cocoa GCD api for connecting. I want to proxify that.

This is as far as I have got:

The call-chain is somewhat long but here is a part of it:

```
* frame #0: 0x00007fff894e7e93 libsystem_network.dylib`tcp_connection_create
frame #1: 0x00007fff83f776cf CFNetwork`SocketStream::startTCPConnection_Host(__CFHost*, __CFNumber const*) + 767
...
frame #3: 0x00007fff83f746ff CFNetwork`SocketStream::open(void const*, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 295
....
frame #9: 0x00007fff83fa3e7a CFNetwork`HTTPWriteFilter::_streamImpl_Open(CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 200
....
frame #12: 0x00007fff83fa3d79 CFNetwork`NetConnection::openConnectionStreams() + 39
...
frame #18: 0x00007fff83fa31d9 CFNetwork`HTTPProtocol::openStream() + 255
....
frame #34: 0x00007fff8d7ae967 Foundation`+[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
frame #35: 0x00007fff8d7ae76b Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1318
```

Now I can intercept `tcp_connection_create`, but I was unable to find any kind of documentation on what the functions arguments are.

Where can I find the prototye/argument types for `tcp_connection_create`? Are any sources available?
Or is there a better approach. I know that this does not call `socket`/`connect` further down.

Comment: Just 5 minutes in and you're already the second result for `tcp_connection_create` on Google.

Comment: Other than that, have you considered using [OS X's System Configuration API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096154/programmatically-change-system-network-proxy-settings) to change proxy settings?

Comment: @zneak I don't want to change the system-global proxy settings. I would loose access to local intranet. I want to be able to set proxies on application-level.